# What happens if an orchestrator function is triggered again before the last activity of the last trigger is finished?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Let's say that the orchestrator takes 3 minutes to complete all its activities, but I trigger the orchestrator again after 2 minutes (with different input). Will the orchestrator cancel the first run or will it wait for the first run to be completed and then run the second run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the orchestrator cancel the first run

**No**, Orchestration functions cannot cancel the previous running orchestration function.

Orchestration function can run quickly, so we can call the orchestration function quickly but when it comes to **activity function it waits for the completion**.

> will it wait for the first run to be completed and then run the second run

**Yes**, it will wait for the first orchestration durable function to complete it tasks.

Because the Durable function uses the Azure storage. It keeps stores the whole runtime states in a storage.

As per the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-perf-and-scale#azure-storage-provider) **Durable functions Performance and scale** below activities are happens while running the Durable Function

- Function executions are stored in Azure storage Queues.
- Orchestration, Entity status and history stored in Azure Tables.
- Azure Blobs and blob leases are used to distribute orchestration instances and entities across multiple app instances.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288577/azure-durable-orchestration-function-triggering-twice) for more information